# Undefined when reading length with nested for loops in JAVA SCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, nested-for-loop

```
let arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

for (let i=arr.length;i>=0;i--){
  console.log(arr[i]);
  for (let n=arr[i].length;n>=0;n--){
    console.log(arr[i][n]);
  }
}
```

Comment: arr.length is 3 in your example. Which means that only arr[0],arr[1] and arr[2] have a value. Your for loop correctly includes 0 (condition is i>=0, not i<0), but incorrectly starts with i=3, which is not a valid index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read out of range of arrays. Add `-1`

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
  for (let n = arr[i].length - 1;/* While accessing index, always consider `length - 1` */ n >= 0; n--) {
    console.log(arr[i][n]);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much brother....i am learning the basics of JS ....but i have stuck with this problem since 2 hours .....but you solved it ..thank u thank u ...

Comment: I would personally ask a question here only after days of research https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users